# Net::SMTPUnknownError: charset=UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

I get this error message when I try to send an email with a pdf attachment. I make use of wickedpdf to generate the pdf. I tried including the option :encoding => 'UTF-8' in the pdf generation but still no luck. Please enlighten!

Answer (score 0):

The PDF should come as an `application/pdf` attachment, and this attachment type does not support a `charset` attribute.  Apparently you are passing this argument to the attachment routine, though, not the generator.